# google geo coding with json and php

Tags: php, json, curl

My php file:

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['query'])) {  
    $query = $_POST['query'];

$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';
$callback="&callback=?";
$sensor='&sensor=false';
$result= $url.$query.$sensor.$callback;
curl_init ($result);

 }
?>
```

My html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


    // when the user clicks the button
    $("button").click(function(){


          $.getJSON("geo.php",function(json){

             $('#results').append('<p>Latitude : ' + json.results[9].geometry.location.lat+ '</p>');
             $('#results').append('<p>Longitude: ' + json.results[9].geometry.location.lng+ '</p>');

});

          // get the json file
    });
});


</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="query" /><button>Get Coordinates</button>
<div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I get this error when i used firbug:

```
json is null
$('#results').append('<p>...s[9].geometry.location.lat+ '</p>');
```

Google's json response:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "street_address" ],
    "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "1600",
      "short_name": "1600",
      "types": [ "street_number" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "types": [ "route" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Mountain View",
      "short_name": "Mountain View",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "California",
      "short_name": "CA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "94043",
      "short_name": "94043",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 37.4219720,
        "lng": -122.0841430
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 37.4188244,
          "lng": -122.0872906
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 37.4251196,
          "lng": -122.0809954
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

EDITED:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['query'])) {  
    $query = $_POST['query'];
$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=';
$callback="&callback=?";
$sensor='&sensor=false';
$result= $url.$query.$sensor.$callback;
$resp = file_get_contents($result);
                header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
                header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
                header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $resp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are capturing the result?

I'm assuming this:
Your PHP code is called via Ajax from the html.
So basically you are constructing the URL for the query and using CURL to fetch the json result.
It seems you are not actually capturing or returning the results to the ajax call
You might want to do this:

```
            $process = curl_init($url); 
//init curl connection
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

              curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

            curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);

            $resp = curl_exec($process); 
//your content
            curl_close($process); 
//$resp contains your response
                header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
                header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
                header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $resp;
```

Comment: Ok Try calling the script directly and use error_log to help you debug this. I find that debugging with error_log and print_r helps me see where in te code there is an error.

Comment: error_log(print_r($vartocheck,true),3,"destination of log file"); also don't forget to check the apache log file for the errors, maybe you are simply overlooking another error.

Comment: Can u tell me what is destination log file? Do i have to create it or it already present. so that i just have to point to it

Comment: either is valid. You can create it and assign rights so that apache can write to it. or you can use an existing file. touch logfile.txt; chmod 777 logfile.txt then just set the complete path to it in script.

Comment: and if you have ssh access, you can actually tail -f the log file and you 'll get real time log info.

Comment: error_log(print_r($ch,true),3,"C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\logs\access.log");   Is this is right?

Comment: yes, that is right. You should be able to write there. I tested this http://pastie.org/1459563 and get a json back "request denied though" but it still works. so the code should be ok, now the problem is either your curl is not installed on your php ( try creating a test php file with only php_info() in it. and looking at the result if curl is intalled. again check the apache error logs

Comment: I checked there are no errors.It has some old error logs dated dec 2008 There is no curl extension present in php_info() file.These are extensions i found..PHP Extension  20090626
Zend Extension  220090626
Zend Extension Build  API220090626,TS,VC6
PHP Extension Build  API20090626,TS,VC6

Comment: My bad it was phpinfo(); Now you should get a whole sectino on curl, this means that you don't have curl installed or active.. what is weird is that you SHOULD be getting an error, try using file_get_contents instead :http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php...

Comment: I see curl enabled.I did this....  click the WAMP icon in task tray, then go to PHP > PHP Extensions > php_curl. Then restart apache. Yeah that is phpinfo().In wamp u have direct link to that page no need of creating i.

Comment: Thanks..its working.Is something wrong with this line:  $('#results').append('<p>Latitude : ' + json.results[9].geometry.location.lat+ '</p>') I get undefined error

Comment: so it definitely was something with your curl.

Comment: hhey i pasted edited php above it again gives json null error.Directly loading php is working.When i take value from html json is null error is occuring

Comment: try now debugging your js. Alert the json object inside the callback function to see if you are getting your values. Vague errors like that usually mean that the js was not properly inserted in the code.. something is causing the interpreter to crash. comment lines and start adding them back in until you get the error.

Comment: bobby that just confirms my theory, your JS is has an error somewhere, check with dev tools to see if your included files are acutally included, something is not allowing the js interpreter to load the whole code..

Comment: ok also one thing occurs to me... is your geo.php in the root of your website? try passing te complete URL to the ajax call.

Comment: all i get inside the callback function is null.I tried to alert json object it gives me null.I tried alert(json); It gives me null.I also tried alert(json.results[9].geometry.location.lat);I get same response

Comment: I gave the complete url to geo.php as  $.getJSON("C:\wamp\www\geo.php",function(json) >Then i get this error "uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x805e000a [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]" nsresult: "0x805e000a (<unknown>)" location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js :: anonymous :: line 127" data: no]"  Is this same origin error?

Comment: so basically nothing is being returned. try changing th ajax call to the full URL to the geo.php script

Comment: no no, C:\wamp\www\geo.php is not accesible through the web, you need to provide a rul, something like h t t p ://yourdomain.com/geo.php

Comment: So it works only if i get a domain? but my geo.php is in my root so $.getJSON("geo.php",function(json) should work.Should i really have domain to do this?

Comment: no, it should be working from there I am just checking, you can also do this : h t t p ://localhost/geo.php also, you can always edit your hosts file to simulate a domain.. what I'm trying to say, is, are you sure that the ajax call is getting where it should? use pastie.org to put your code so that I can see if I see something else (js and php).

Comment: you need to urlencode your query.$result= $url.urlencode($query).$sensor.$callback;

Comment: what is the search string you are using

Comment: Its my city name Hyderabad. Just one word.Does it give a problem?

Comment: I tried "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy" its the same error i am getting.

Comment: I figured it out... problem is you are not passing your query to your ajax call. you have to add the get parameter query to your ajax request ("geo.php?query="+$('#query') .....

Comment: ok here is a working copy http://pastie.org/1459840 problem was you are not passing what was input in the input type text field. also when constructing the appends, you were using the sub-index 9, be careful it could be out of bounds.

Comment: The query is going right GET http://localhost/geo.php?query=hyderabad
 
but the alert still shows json object as null

Comment: working for me http://stats.o-i.es/test.html  codes are the one before and this one http://pastie.org/1459875 also do realize that on my server the php s name was test.php so change that in your html in case you have not.

Comment: Thank god its working I have been working on it like days im new to all these.Now got idea about these things.I also had same problems when working with google url shortner.I guess il be able to work it out fine.Thanks a lot for ur effort and time

Comment: hhey is there a problem with my curl?should i reinstall wamp server?

Comment: I don't know , my curl code had a small mistake in it it stated :  $process = curl_init($url); when it should have been  $process =  $process = curl_init($result); now it works.

Comment: why it should be $process = $process = curl_init($result); If u have time can u tell me.

Comment: no no  $process = curl_init($result); ( the $result, the parameter was wrong), that other stuff is the stack overflow comment system giving me headaches

Answer (score 2):

You're not outputting anything from the PHP. The PHP script has to output JSON for getJSON to be able to receive it.

Have a look at [curl_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php). I think you want to be doing this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $result);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks.I was expecting curl will output directly.

Comment: Try visiting the URL of your PHP script directly and debug from there.

Comment: You need to debug the PHP - the issue isn't in the JavaScript. Trying putting some echo statements in there to see if everything you thought was working is actually working. Sorry, can't help any more than that!

Comment: I have tried echoing $url,$sensor,$callback ...all get is a blank page.

Comment: Ok, change `($_POST['query'])` to `($_REQUEST['query'])` and pass the query in as a query string - e.g. "geo.php?New+York". The problem is that everything is wrapped in a check for a post parameter which isn't being sent when you do a GET.